# Saving Codeigniter Tokens

Tags: php, codeigniter

Upon enabling the CSRF Protection feature of the Codeigniter, I found out that there is a hidden field containing the value.
`<input type="hidden" name="token_name" value="$token_value">`

I wanted to extend the function of this field, and I wanted to put the value on the database. However, it is unretrievable via `$this->input->post('token_name')`

Is it possible to retrieve the token value? Or nah?

Answer (score 0):

> Upon enabling the CSRF Protection feature of the Codeigniter, I found out that there is a hidden field containing the value.

How did you add the hidden csrf field to your form. If you use the `form_helper` CI class, then CI will automatically do it for you, otherwise, you have to manually set add something like this to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />
```

From CI3 docs:

> If you use the form helper, then form_open() will automatically insert a hidden csrf field in your forms. If not, then you can use get_csrf_token_name() and get_csrf_hash()

If you did neither of the above, then I don't think the hidden `input` field you are talking about relates to csrf protection. To verify, disable csrf from `config.php` and check whether its still there.

Comment: I didn't add the hidden field. It was automatically inserted, yes.

Comment: In that case, check two things: First, do you see a proper generated csrf code when you right click the browser and see the source? Secondly, what do you get when you try to fetch $_POST["token_name"]?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do what you want.

`token_name` is set in `application/config/config.php` with this.

```
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'name_of_your_choice';
```

So you can retrieve it by reading from config

```
$tokenName = $this->config->item('csrf_token_name');
```

Or it can be gotten from the always available `security` class

```
$tokenName = $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
```

The reason it is unretrievable via `$this->input->post('token_name')` is that the input class strips the hidden CSRF field info with `unset()` before it reaches your controller.